# Может ли хостер украсть мои php скрипты?

Tags: php, хостинг

Бывали ли у вас такие прецеденты?

Comment: Конечно может. Ему даже делать для этого ничего не надо. Вы же сами выкладываете свои скрипты на его сервера.

Comment: @Sergey Верно подмечено!

Comment: Если ваш код приносит деньги, у вас хватит их на собственный сервер. Пока скрипты не приносят денег, чтобы хватало на сервер, — поверьте, они никому не нужны.

Comment: @VladD Но ведь и к выделенному серверу у хостера будет физический доступ.

Comment: @Khipster: Не, на _свой_ сервер, не сервер у хостера. Вы можете себе представить, чтобы Microsoft, например, хостилась у какого-то хостера?

Comment: @VladD они хостятся у Apple. Инфа сотка

Answer (score 18, accepted):

У хост-провайдера есть доступ к вашим скриптам. Однако, о таких прецедентах я никогда не слышал. Хост-провайдер зарабатывает на предоставлении вам услуг и заинтересован в том, чтобы предоставлять их и дальше. Заработать на другом виде бизнеса у него не очень много шансов - нужно понимать вашу бизнес-модель, нужно поддерживать код, создавать команду разработчиков, перетянуть клиентов. Т.е. не просто украсть код, а создать новый тип бизнеса и вложить в это деньги (с немалой долей вероятности их потерять).

На самом деле из крупных игроков никто не использует чужой код, даже если есть возможность. Код сам по себе без разработчиков не работает, его нужно постоянно поддерживать, так как изменяются версии и возможности программного обеспечения, изменяется нагрузка и потребности клиентов. Код работает пока есть команда, поддерживающая его. Если команды нет — код умирает. Если вы отдаете код другой команде, в 80% случаев вы получаете легаси-код, поддерживать который очень накладно и рано или поздно встает вопрос о разработке новой версии с нуля.

Comment: Значит надо сжать код как следует чтобы точно никто ничего не понял.

Comment: Можно, но на самом деле лучше поменьше тратить время на защиту Web-приложений и побольше на разработку. Когда вы набираете клиентов - вопрос самого кода становится делом девятым. Никто не будет добывать код, если захотят скопировать ваш проект - возьмут идею (а идеи не патентуются) и разработают ПО с нуля, силами своей команды. Чтобы быть впереди, вам нужно постоянно развивать продукт и не тратить время на лишние телодвижения по его защите - опасности для вашего проекта и дела будут приходить с других сторон.

Comment: @Khipsterm  , cheops Так хостеры тырят код не для себя, а для дальнейшей перепродажи каким-либо заинтересованным лицам. В этом профит, а не в том, чтоб украсть и использовать самим лично.. В этом выгода. Поанализировав рынок - можно узнать, что больше ищут на данный момент....... А прецеденты есть и не мало. Банально в последнее время жаловались на Hostinger.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, возможно какой-то инженер мог попробовать так заработать, компания-хостер вряд ли заинтересована даже в ложных обвинениях, тем более, в условиях, когда хост-рынок сужается из-за экспансии облачных компаний. Не исключены и происки конкурентов. Однако, ценности в сыром коде не так много, использовать его без доработки и поддержки дороже, чем собственную разработку. Еще более его дорого использовать, если на хостинге собранный сайт с компилированными и минифицированными ассетами, которые попадают туда в результате деплоя - чиканешься такую копию поддерживать.

Comment: @cheops вот именно, что можно стырить, а потом сказать, что это происки конкурентов. А тырить в большинстве своем можно с не очень опытных, но которые разрабатывают довольно популярные вещи. Банально везде уже загаженные - браузерные mmo, а ля Бойцовский клуб... Таких спокойно можно сливать не напрягаясь.  Ведь банально и утрируя можно сказать "а у вас на компьютере вирусы", вот у вас и стырили, а мы не причем.....Тут, как говорится, дело техники. Изыскать можно.

Answer (score 9):

В теории может.

Но чтобы ты был уверен в том, что он не станет этого делать, прочитай договор, который ты с ними заключил. Там должно быть прописано, что они не претендуют на твои коды. Конкретной формулировки не скажу, просто читай и вникай.

И то, этот договор дает тебе шанс выиграть в суде и не более того. Т.е. он не является гарантией защищенности.